# Automatic sync realm with server

Tags: ios, swift, restkit, realm

Im using realm with some api and i want to reach the behavior when i delete object at server it should be automatically deleted on the app.
With CoreData there is a RestKit framework that do the trick, does realm have something similar. I ve tried ObjectMapper and Alamofire with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to take care yourself of the object deletion. This might look like below:

```
Alamofire.request(.DELETE, "http://localhost:3000/product/\(object.id).json")
         .response { request, response, data, error in
             // TODO: Replace through appropriate error handling
             precondition(error == nil, "An error occurred \(error!)")
             let realm = try! Realm()
             try! realm.write {
                 realm.delete(object)
             }
         }
```